# Get the comments on all images inside a folder

Tags: python, image, google-drive-api

Good afternoon. I have just created a code that takes an image id and returns the comments on that image. I have a folder of about 100 images and I would like to create a code that will pick up each one of these images one by one and return the comments. The code I created is included below:

```
def retrieve_comments(service, file_id):
  """Retrieve a list of comments.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to retrieve comments for.
  Returns:
    List of comments.'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
  """

  try:
    comments = service.comments().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
    return comments.get('items', [])
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
  return None


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

service = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
comment = retrieve_comments(service, '18h-MkLdhqeHZ45pIiDZ3G5RkqJm6Pwh0')[0]['content']
```

Comment: Google supports [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch). Do you have any specific questions about it?

Answer (score 0):

**In order to retrieve the images inside a folder, you will have to make a `files.list` request and supply a `q` query parameter.**

The q parameter looks like this:

```
q = 'IMAGE_FOLDER_ID' in parents and mimeType = 'image/png' # or other mime type
```

And the request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='IMAGE_FOLDER_ID'%20in%20parents%20and%20mimeType%20%3D%20'image%2Fpng'
```

As for translating this into Python:

```
response = drive_service.files().list(q= "'IMAGE_FOLDER_ID' in parents and mimeType = 'image/png'").execute()
for file in response.get('files', []):
   # retrieve the comments for each file
```

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list);
- [Drive API v3 search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#python);
- [Drive API v3 search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms).